# Is it possible to have IF statement in an Echo statement in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, echo, nested

Thanks in advance.  I did look at the other questions/answers that were similar and didn't find exactly what I was looking for.

I'm trying to do this, am I on the right path?

```
echo " <div id='tabs-".$match."'>

    <textarea id='".$match."' name='".$match."'>".

    if ($COLUMN_NAME === $match)
        {
        echo $FIELD_WITH_COLUMN_NAME;
        }

    else
        {
        }

    ."</textarea>

<script type='text/javascript'>
CKEDITOR.replace( '".$match."' );
</script>

</div>";
```

I am getting the following error message in the browser:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF

Please let me know if this is the right way to go about nesting an IF statement inside an echo.  Thank you.

Comment: *Why* you would want to write code like that? Assign it to a variable, and then echo that. Even better, look into the MVC design pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work

```
$val = ""; 
if ($COLUMN_NAME === $match)
        {
        $val =  $FIELD_WITH_COLUMN_NAME;
        }
echo " <div id='tabs-".$match."'>

    <textarea id='".$match."' name='".$match."'>".    $val    ."</textarea>

<script type='text/javascript'>
CKEDITOR.replace( '".$match."' );
</script>

</div>";
```

Answer (score 4):

No. You can however use the ternary operator.

```
$a = 0;
echo 'Foo ' . ($a == 0 ? 'zero' : 'non-zero') . ' Bar';
```

Note the `()`, you need them.

Answer (score 3):

Use the PHP ternary operator, you can read more about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

```
echo " <div id='tabs-".$match."'>    
    <textarea id='".$match."' name='".$match."'>".
    ($COLUMN_NAME==$match ? $FIELD_WITH_COLUMN_NAME : "").
     "</textarea>    
      <script type='text/javascript'>
      CKEDITOR.replace( '".$match."' );
     </script>    
     </div>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't nest an `if` inside an `echo`. You need either to split the `echo` into separate statements:

```
echo " <div id='tabs-".$match."'>

    <textarea id='".$match."' name='".$match."'>";

    if ($COLUMN_NAME === $match)
        {
        echo $FIELD_WITH_COLUMN_NAME;
        }

echo "</textarea>

<script type='text/javascript'>
CKEDITOR.replace( '".$match."' );
</script>

</div>";
```

or to use [the ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary):

```
echo " <div id='tabs-".$match."'>

    <textarea id='".$match."' name='".$match."'>".

    (($COLUMN_NAME === $match) ? $FIELD_WITH_COLUMN_NAME : "")

    ."</textarea>

<script type='text/javascript'>
CKEDITOR.replace( '".$match."' );
</script>

</div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

use `... . ($COLUMN_NAME === $match) ? $FIELD-WITH_COLUMN_NAME : '' .  ...`

dismiss the if in front of it